# How to get alert before open and after closed popup

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working in angular 2:How to get alert after closed the popup  and before  open the popup.I did partialy but it is not working properly.Can you find where i did misatke from my script. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtzmdm?file=src/app/dialog/dialog.component.ts

```
 export class popComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
 @Input() visible: boolean; 
 ngOnChanges() { 
 if(this.visible==true){ 
 alert("popup will open"); 
 }   
 if(this.visible==false){ 
 alert("popup closed"); 
 }  
 }
```